# jQuery: Toggle Form Field with .find()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've been trying to animate a comments form with .slideToggle(). Unfortunately, the form is repeated three times (WordPress posts) - so I had to use .find() to target the specific toggle being clicked to prevent all form fields from toggling.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery(".single-comments").toggle()
});
    jQuery(".comment-toggle").click(function() {
      jQuery("this").find(".single-comments").slideToggle('fast');
    });
</script>
```

The above script doesn't cause all .single-comments divs to toggle, but toggles the form when any field in clicked (obviously), since .single-comments (form div) is a child of .comment-toggle. I changed it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery(".single-comments").toggle()
});
    jQuery(".comment-toggle").click(function() {
      jQuery(".single-comments").find("#respond").slideToggle('fast');
    });
</script>
```

in a futile attempt to circumvent the problem. #respond is another div within .single-comments that the form sits within. However, with the second snippet, .comment-toggle simply doesn't respond to clicks - slideToggle is simply not called. If anyone has any ideas, would be greatly appreciated by me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should not enclose `this` in *quotes* in selector. If you enclose this in quotes it will be considered as `tag name` instead of current event source object. If you have framework 4 and above then you can use ClientIDMode="static" This will keep the `ClientID` as the server side id.

*Change*

```
jQuery("this").find(".single-comments").slideToggle('fast');
```

*To*

```
jQuery(this).find(".single-comments").slideToggle('fast');
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem, as my form sits within div.single-comments - which is in turn a child of div.comment-toggle - causing my form to be hidden whenever one of its fields is clicked.

Comment: Mr @Adil is right...now this should work, 1 up from me

Comment: I've changed it to (find); the form is still hiding itself because ".single-comments" is a child of ".comment-toggle".

Answer (score 0):

Try using `jQuery(this).find("#respond").slideToggle('fast')`

Comment: Unfortunately this also causes .comment-toggle to stop responding to click events :/

Comment: you better try something like `$(document).ready(function(){ //your events });`

Comment: Will try although not sure how that will help - I don't think ready state is an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. For those who would like to know how to solve the problem: don't use the .find() method as this only selects descendants of the element in initial jQuery object.

Instead, put both the toggling element and the element to be toggled in another div, and use the .siblings() method, and pass the specific selector into the .siblings() method as an argument. This causes the click event only to bind to that specific instance of the div (div.single-comments in this case), without affecting other identical divs in the rest of the document. Cheers!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".comment-toggle").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).siblings(".single-comments").slideToggle('fast');
```